# Is possible to convert own Android app to Chrome app?

Tags: android, converters, google-chrome-app

I created my first app for Android and today i discovered Chrome apps. Can i make compatible my app for running in Google Chrome? Can i convert it?

Does exist any tool to create the same app compatible for Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

I have found following solution on the itnernet:

Easier way:
http://android.wonderhowto.com/how-to/convert-your-favorite-android-apps-into-chrome-apps-0157594/

http://lifehacker.com/how-to-run-android-apps-inside-chrome-on-any-desktop-op-1637564101

Comment: I found the same but i tought it was an end-user solution. So for developers isn't there an official tool/way? Thank you

Comment: I did convert the app with ARChon Packager, but when i try to load in Chromium (to test it before publishing), it says that the file manifest is missing or unreadable. What could be the problem?

Comment: The problem might be in chrome manifest (maybe some access settings). Unfortunately I don´t have any knowlege about that issue. Let us know if you will find the answer.

Comment: I solved adding `"message": "App"` in messages.json but now nothing happens after adding it to Chrome extensions